# Masking the app preview view on Android

Tags: android

When you place an Android app into the background and then press and hold the home button you can see a list of active apps and a preview still image of where you were in the app.

Can this preview be changed or removed at all? I've tried altering the view during the activities onPause() method but had no joy.

[image: App preview]

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove it you can try adding

`<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true">`

to your Manifest file.